# Why doesn't my Eclipse IDE allow write override annotation when I implement interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, overriding

When I write following code in my Eclipse IDE

```
interface I {
    void m();
}
class A implements I{
    @Override
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("1");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().m();
    }
}
```

I see following message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The method m() of type A must override a superclass method

Is it bug of my IDE?

P.S.

online compiler compile this code sucessfully

[online compiler result](http://ideone.com/zgGeSm)

Comment: Either Eclipse is dumb or your Java compiler isn't >= 1.6

Comment: @LMeyer java version "1.6.0_38"

Comment: I get the same error if I set the project compiler compliance level to v1.5, when using Java 6 or 7. Check that in your project properties.

Comment: @Duncan  Actually - it is true. I change compilance level to 1.6 and profit!

Comment: Yeah I meant Compiler compliance level sorry.

Comment: LMeyer or Duncan If you want accepted answer you can make answer